# DirectoryIterator create dropdown menu, PHP

Tags: php, menu, drop-down-menu

I tried to make a drop down menu with DirectoryIterator and superFish/jQuery plugin but it's proving quite difficult.

My code is here:

```
$directory = dirname(__FILE__)."/products";


function dropdown($dirname)
{
    $products = new DirectoryIterator($dirname);

    echo '<ul class="sf-menu">';
    foreach ($products as $dirinfo) 
    {
        if($dirinfo->isDot()) continue; //skip . and ..
        if ($dirinfo->isDir()) 
        {
            echo '<li>'.$dirinfo->getFilename() .'</li>';
            if(is_dir($dirinfo->getPath()))
            {
                dropdown($dirinfo->getPath());
            }


        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

dropdown($directory);
```

Basically I want to display all folders and subfolders from products.

thanks, Robert

Answer (score 0):

Your nested `ul`s must be within an `li`. Close your `li` element *after* your recursive `dropdown` call.